# How to remove a duplicate ID in a li which has a specific class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to remove a duplicate ID in a li that has a specific class. For example in this list, there are duplicates Ids (small, medium) and I would like to remove the Ids with class "size". How can I do this?

```
<ul id="bulk">
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="size" value="47">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="size" value="47">Medium</li>
   <li id="Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">Large</li>
   <li id="X-Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">X-Large</li>
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="active" value="">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="active" value="">Medium</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is something like this

```
<ul id="bulk">
       <li id="Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">Large</li>
       <li id="X-Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">X-Large</li>
       <li id="Small" name="size" class="active" value="">Small</li>
       <li id="Medium" name="size" class="active" value="">Medium</li>
   </ul>
```

I have tried this code below but it doesn't work

```
<script>
   uniqueLi = {};
   
   $("#bulk li").each(function () {
     var thisVal = $(this).text();
   
     if ( !(thisVal in uniqueLi) ) {
       uniqueLi[thisVal] = "";
     } else {
       $(this).remove();
     }
   })
      
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why you ended up with duplicated `id`s since it should be unique, but if you can't avoid this, maybe a selector as `.size#Small` can select the first match and do what you want, but since there's duplicated ids, maybe unexpected behavior can happen

Comment: that is a good question. Why do you have duplicate ids in the first place?

Comment: I have colors and sizes(small,medium,large,x-large), each color has it's own sizes so if I click color red which has size small and medium I wanted the all list of colors to display but highlighting only small and medium sizes that is why I was trying to replace the ids @Aristeidis Karavas

Comment: I gave you an answer below as well but have to agree with the others. It is weird to have mutple Ids also based on naming conventions you should use small letters for ids.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// make an array of the elements
let bulkItems = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('#bulk .size') ];

for (let i = 0; i < bulkItems.length; i++) {
  // get the id for the item being evaluated
  let thisId = bulkItems[i].id;
  
  // filter out the ones that are duplicates
  bulkItems = bulkItems.filter((it, index) => {
    // if the indexes are the same, it's the same item, include it
    // if the ids are not the same, it's not a duplicate, include it
    if (i === index || it.id !== thisId) return true;
    
    // it's not the same element, and it has the same id
    // remove it from the DOM, and exclude it from the results
    it.parentNode.removeChild(it);
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="bulk">
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="size" value="47">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="size" value="47">Medium</li>
   <li id="Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">Large</li>
   <li id="X-Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">X-Large</li>
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="active" value="">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="active" value="">Medium</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know what to add more than `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to make it work like the snippet above but it doesn't work @Taplar

Comment: This solution does not use jQuery at all.  It uses vanilla javascript. @user11710915

Comment: I have checked again and try it , it only remove duplicate without checking classes. I wanted to remove the duplicate with `class=size` right now it removes the duplicate with `class=active` eg this should remain since they have class=active `<li id="Small" name="size" class="active" value="">Small</li>
       <li id="Medium" name="size" class="active" value="">Medium</li>` @Taplar

Comment: @user11710915 Updated.  To limit it to those with the class of size, then the `li` part of the selector just has to change to `.size`

Comment: Now it doesn't remove anything @Taplar

Comment: Right, because in the example given, none of the `class="size"` ids are duplicated.

Comment: What I'm trying to archive is to remove the class=size(elements) which their `Ids` are the same as in class=active like `id="Small" class="size"` and `id="Medium" class="size"` are the same as `id="Small" class="active" and `id="Medium" class="active"` So how can I remove the ones with class = "size" ?@Taplar

Answer (score 1):

I assume the content is loaded dynamically and once one of those are active you have multiple ids? Anyways foreach is a good start but the uniqueLi makes no sense for me as it is empty. By using hasClass you can check if that li has the class "active" in it.

What you could do is go through all ids and just check for that.
I made a snipet for you

```js
$("#bulk li").each(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass("active") ) {
            $id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+$id+".size").remove();
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="bulk">
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="size" value="47">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="size" value="47">Medium</li>
   <li id="Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">Large</li>
   <li id="X-Large" name="size" class="size" value="47">X-Large</li>
   <li id="Small" name="size" class="active" value="">Small</li>
   <li id="Medium" name="size" class="active" value="">Medium</li>
</ul>
```

I changed the jquery element. Assuming that the active class causes the multiple id issue, I use the function to find all active classes. By having the ids of those I then delete those that has the same id but with a different class -> "size".

Comment: I have tried this but is not working because it removes all the class active, I want to remove only the duplicate id (small and medium) with class=size not class=active @K Nugal

Comment: I edited my answer from before. please upvote the answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is not working yet and also I wanted it dynamic not like `$("#Small,#Medium,#Large,#X-Large")` because what if I have size like `180inch, 65gb` @K Nugal

Comment: That is hard to tell since you did not give specifics of how your code is being built. In your  case if you want it dynamic then just #bulk li same effect. Of course this only works if you create those acive classes with the same ids. One more thing you do not need to add the script for jquery as you already use it.

Comment: Hey, your code was working at first then I found out that is not working as expected because I use loop so what happens is I have sizes and colors if I click one of the size I want it to show colors which belongs to that size. What happens now is if I click size it display colors that belong to the size as expected but if I click again it keeps adding them below and not removing. So the problem is it only work one time how can I fix this please? I really appreciate your help @K Nugal

Comment: If you help me fix that I'll accept the answer @K Nugal

Comment: since you click on something to create the multiple ids why not hook that function to  the click event. Then it will always fire when you add multiple ids. Then again I am not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
let small = document.querySelectorAll('#small');
        if (small.length > 1) {
            for (const smalls of small) {
                if (smalls.classList.contains('size')) {
                    smalls.remove();
                }
            }
        }
```